# Type inference of higher-kinded type argument identity in scala

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, higher-kinded-types

I have a type class

```
trait ResponseHandler[+A, -B[_]] {
  def handle[C](response: WSResponse, parser: A => B[C]): HTTPCallResult[C]
}
```

and its instance

```
  type Identity[X] = X
  implicit object JsonResponseHandler extends ResponseHandler[JsValue, Identity] {
    def handle[C](response: WSResponse, parser: JsValue => C): HTTPCallResult[C] = {
      // implementation
    }
  }
```

When calling function

```
post[A, In, Out[_]](parser: In => Out[A])(implicit handler: ResponseHandler[In, Out]) = {
  // implementation
}
```

like this

```
post { resp: WSResponse =>
  resp.body == "alive"
}
```

it throws a compile time error

```
[error] no type parameters for method post: (parser: In => Out[A])(implicit handler: ResponseHandler[In,Out]) exist so that it can be applied to arguments (WSResponse => Boolean)
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : WSResponse => Boolean
[error]  required: ?In => ?Out[?A]
[error]       .post { resp: WSResponse =>
[error]        ^
[error]  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse => Boolean
[error]  required: In => Out[A]
[error]       .post { resp: WSResponse =>
[error]                                ^
[error]  ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both object WSResponseHandler in object ResponseHandler of type 
[error]  ResponseHandler.WSResponseHandler.type
[error]  and object WSResponseWithErrorsHandler in object ResponseHandler of type ResponseHandler.WSResponseWithErrorsHandler.type
[error]  match expected type ResponseHandler[Any,Out]
[error]       .post { resp: WSResponse =>
[error]             ^
[error] three errors found
```

However, when called like this

```
import ResponseHandler.Identity
post { resp: WSResponse =>
  (resp.body == "alive").asInstanceOf[Identity[Boolean]]
}
```

it works. Is it possible to somehow help compiler infer the type? I tried `def getIdtentity[A](a: A): Identity[A] = a.asInstanceOf[Identity[A]]`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
def post[A, In, O, Out[_]](parser: In => O)(implicit 
  handler: ResponseHandler[In, Out], 
  ev: O <:< Out[A]
) = ???
```

This should help to infer types.

The order of implicits `handler`, `ev` is significant.

Other options:

```
ev: O =:= Out[A]
ev: Out[A] =:= O
ev: O =:= Out[A], ev1: Out[A] =:= O
ev: Out[A] <:< O
ev: O <:< Out[A], ev1: Out[A] <:< O
ev: O => Out[A]
ev: Out[A] => O
ev: O => Out[A], ev1: Out[A] => O
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, however, now I must specify `A` parameter when calling the function, since the type cant be inferred from the parser method `In => O`. It results in `Nothing`.

Comment: @DavidTomecek Not sure I understand completely. I tested with code samples you provided. Could you update your question with code sample where you have to specify `A`?

Comment: @DavidTomecek https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/ubzPwWXHQsWW7jwN67Ip6w/3

Comment: @DavidTomecek Did you have a chance to prepare code snippet where you have to specify `A`?

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not respond earlier. At the end I changed the overall design of the code, that resulted in simpler implementation. Nonetheless, the problem was that the post method was supposed to return say `Option[A]`. The proposed solution then resulted in `A` being inferred as `Nothing`. So for instance `post(f: WSResponse => Int)` resulted in `Option[Nothing]` instead of `Option[Int]`.

Comment: However, again I am very sorry I didn't respond earlier. I hope it did not come through ungrateful. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @DavidTomecek No problem. Thanks for your response. It's a little weird. At scastie you can see that the type is inferred `Option[Boolean]` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/huiRmXsyQq2K0RQxObIY9w/4 Maybe I reproduced the behavior not identically.

Comment: `Unpack1` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062238/filter-a-hlist-using-a-supertype

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2712